# Getting a random number while trying load a number from a file

Tags: java, swing

## EDIT: I am trying to create a "clicker" game, that loads the last recorded number from the *data* file.

I am working on a simple, *one* ***button*** game, it is a clicker game. Nothing fancy, just a `JButton` and a `JLabel`. I'm fairly new at the Java IO Class, so I don't know what's causing this to happen. I'm not getting any errors, but a random number, except the same number every time.

## Write Method:

```
public static void write(long data) {

    File file = new File("data.txt");
    path = file.getAbsolutePath();

    try {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);
        writer.println(data);
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

## Read Method:

```
public static long read() {

    long data = 0;
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        data = reader.read();
        reader.close();
        return data;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.format("Exception occurred trying to read '%s'.", path);
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

## Graphical User Interface:

```
public static void gui() {

    . . .

    // Declarations {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Clicker");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton clickerButton = new JButton("Click");
    JLabel amountOfClicks = new JLabel("Click to get started!");
    // }

    . . .
    // * * * * * * * * * * *
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 0));

    // Action {
    clickerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            if (read() >= 1) {
                clickerCount = read() + 1;
                amountOfClicks.setText("You have clicked: " + clickerCount + " times.");
                write(clickerCount);
            } else {
                clickerCount = clickerCount + 1;
                amountOfClicks.setText("You have clicked: " + clickerCount + " times.");
                write(clickerCount);
            }
        }
    });
    // }
    . . .
```

Also the ***random*** number I get (48), when I click the button it should increase by 1. But now since it starts at "48", first click: increases by 1. Second: 4. Third: 1. Then stops increasing. The reason why I'm wanting to write to a file is so, I can load the last recorded number.

Comment: Usually when storing data to a file for later use within the program I like to use the `Properties` class. https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Comment: You forgot to mention what you're trying to do.

Comment: @shmosel Lol. Well, technically I did, but I didn't I'll edit it. It's just in pieces.

Comment: `data = reader.read();` -> `data = Long.parseLong(reader.readLine());`

Comment: @shmosel That fixed that problem. Thank you! Now just got to fix my saving file.

Comment: @Chris I will take look at that, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @StarCoder If you'd like, I can post an answer describing how to use the `Properties` class.

Comment: @Chris If would, please. And how can you get a specific value from the `Properies`. Because I need to return a number from that file.

Comment: @StarCoder sure thing, give me a few minutes to type it up

Comment: @Chris Okay, thank you! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieving data from a `Properties` File:

### Store Data

First create a `Properties` object and add data to it. You can think of it's behavior similar to a `Map`. Each key has an associated value that is stored. Unfortunately for your case, `Properties` only stores strings, but we can work around that:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("SomeKey", "SomeValue"); // String => String
props.setProperty("AnotherKey", String.valueOf(123456L)); // String => String (Long)
```

And of course `123456L` can be replaced with a variable that is a long (or any other primitive type). For non-primitives, you can use `.toString()`. (See notes at bottom for non-primitives)

To write the data to a file, you need a `FileOutputStream`:

```
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("config.properties");
```

And then to write to that file:

```
props.store(output, null);
```

If you open that file it is plain-text and you will see something that looks like this:

```
#Sun Jul 16 22:47:45 EST 2017
SomeKey=SomeValue
AnotherKey=123456
```

### Read Data

Reading data is just the reverse, now we need a `FileInputStream` and we will call `.load()`.

```
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");

Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(input);
```

Now the final part is accessing the data, remember everything is a string.

```
String someKey = props.getProperty("SomeKey");
long anotherKey = Long.valueOf(props.getProperty("AnotherKey"));
```

And thats all there is to it.

---

*You can use `Long.parseLong(props.getProperty("AnotherKey"))` instead of `.valueOf()`.*

*For non primitives this is most likely NOT the way to go as everything is saved as strings. For non-primitives, look into [`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)*

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it, got it working!

Comment: @StarCoder No Problem :) Also just another note that I'm going to add to the answer - this gets very hairy when using non-primitives. In that case you'll want to look into `Serializable`

Comment: Thank you. You really know your stuff!

Comment: Lots and lots of practice.. Everyones capable, just gotta make it a daily thing. And trust me - you never stop learning.

Comment: Yep. I just got to find another place to learn Java. The one I was taught last year in school was just an, Introduction. Thinking about going to college for it.

Comment: Currently in college myself, but you will never learn as much in school as you will taking on personal projects in your free time. You have to be proactive in programming as there is just soooo much to cover. I haven't seen file i/o like this covered in a class yet.